# Xcode compilation (fatal) error

Tags: ios, xcode

I upgraded my system to OS X Yosemite and now I'm getting this error when I try and build my iOS projects:

fatal error: file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk/usr/include/sysexits.h' has been modified since the precompiled header '/Users/sidatre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project_Chow-dlqpzktxazigviayrdmdiwvrvitj/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Project Chow-Prefix-eswczkpscchtlodgkuyyxqdzoayy/Project Chow-Prefix.pch.pch' was built

Any insights?

Answer (score 0):

Do a clean build. This will remove the precompiled header.

Comment: I cleaned the project as you specified, but it doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

2 things,

1. Go to product->clean in the top bar, this will.. Well... Clean it up, sometimes it won't work in your case so
2. Compile it again, if it's been modified after compiling it.

If this still does not work, then try saving it, then compile it, if it still does not work (which is a bit unlikely) then try going to that exact fault file, just a warning this is a bit risky, so make a backup btw, see what's in it; if you think it's important, see if there is any way of editing it indirectly on Xcode (by writing code), if not then try deleting it then make it again with the same text, just do it yourself. I wouldn't recommend deleting it, but if it is still not working that may be your only option.

I hope this helps.

Comment: unfortunately, this didn't work for me. I tried reinstalling Xcode, but I still get the same error

Comment: Actually, I didn't read the Yosemite bit, are you using Xcode 5, 6 or 6.0.1?

Comment: I'm using 6.0.1, but I managed to fix the error by deleting the Xcode folder in ~/Library